# go to previous page after login using only Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, redirect

Redirecting to previous page after login using only Java Swing or simple Java?? I need this... plz help me..... I dont want to use Jsp or ASp or Servlet here. Can we do this job using only java??  Jbutton4 is LOGIN button. Jbutton3 is REGISTER BUTTON

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    Connection conn=null;
    try{
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        conn =DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();

        String S1 = jTextField1.getText();
        String S2 = jPasswordField1.getText().toString();
        String S3=jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(S1.isEmpty() || S1 == null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please insert a valid user name", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        // if password is blank, warning message shown
        if(S2.isEmpty() || S2 == null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password field is empty", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        int flag=0;
        String sql;
        sql="SELECT * from member where EMAIL='"+S1+"'";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        //System.out.println(rs.next());
        String uname="",pw="",category="";
        while(rs.next()){                       
            uname=rs.getString("EMAIL");
            pw=rs.getString("PASSWORD");
            category=rs.getString("CATEGORY");

            if(uname.matches(S1) && pw.equals(S2)==true && category.matches(S3))
            {
                flag=1;

                if(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()=="VISITOR")
                {
                    setVisible(false);
                    Newvisitor f1= new Newvisitor(S1);
                    f1.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.darkGray);
                    f1.setVisible(true);
                    // jButton6.setVisible(true);
                }
                else if(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()=="ACCOUNTANT")
                {
                    setVisible(false);
                    inter4 f=new inter4();
                    f.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153,153,255));
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
                else if(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()=="ADMINISTRATOR")
                {
                    setVisible(false);
                    Admin f2=new Admin();
                    f2.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.darkGray);
                    f2.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        } 
        if(flag==0)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"login failed");      
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException ss){
        ss.printStackTrace(); 
    }   

}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    setVisible(false);
    NewJFrame21 fF=new NewJFrame21();
    fF.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    fF.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are getting ?

Comment: call new panel and destroy current(login) panel.

Comment: that's not the thing i want. i want to stay in wherever or whichever page the user was,before user logged in.
new panel and destroy panel wont do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a button named `previousButton` and you want go to previous page/frame after login clicking this button,so if your login frame is named as `JFrame1` then this is how you can close current form any open any other form:

```
 private void previousButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    WindowEvent  winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);

    Jframe1  previousFrame = new Jframe1();

    previousFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```